# How to remove the power button from Ctrl+Alt+Del screen ? Windows 10

Tags: windows, registry, windows-10

A have this application where i disable the options presented at **Ctrl+Alt+Del** screen by changing the values in windows registry progamatically. (It is imp that i do this due to security reasons).

Since i have moved the application to Windows 10, i have been able to remove the command list like "Sign out, Lock, Change a password, Switch user etc..".

Till windows 8 changing the value of, HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\NoLogoff and
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\NoClose

from 0 to 1 used to do the trick. However in windows 10, the keys exist but they are not of any help.

Please respond if any one has any clue.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
The application was written in VB6 and it has worked well on CP, Windows 7, 8, 8.1. 
If there are other ways, like suggested by @code gray, where i could change the group policy options programmatically and obtain the desired result i would appreciate the details for them as well.

[image: The detailed problem]

Comment: What does this question have to do with .NET or even C#?

Comment: Editing the registry was never the correct approach. You use Group Policies. To change them, try the included editor, `gpedit.msc`.

Comment: I use the registry because it is my application which changes the value in the registry when its run. It is an automated process and when the application is closed, it restores the values in the registry.
The desktop application is distributed to a large number of clients and one of its security features is to make sure that certain options of windows are disabled. @CodyGray

Comment: That won't work. These values are read from the registry only once, at startup, and then cached. Just because you change them when your app launches doesn't guarantee that they'll take effect. However, if the requirement is that you do this programmatically (that was conspicuously missing from the question), then you can certainly work with Group Policy Objects programmatically. Update your question to ask about that if you want more details. Also consider specifying a language.

Comment: Thanks @CodyGray for the reply. I have updated the question as asked. The application is in VB6 and it has worked well all these years on XP, 7, 8 and 8.1. Please let me know if you can help me in this. I would really appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to identify a possible solution.

For ctrl+Alt+Del screen change the following registry key in Windows 10. If you dont find the "NoClose" key then create one there.

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\policies\Explorer
>   "NoClose"=dword:00000001

For Start menu:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\policies\Explorer
>   "NoClose"=dword:00000001

This solution will not remove the PowerButton Icon from the Ctrl+Alt+Del but it will be of no use.

Hope it helps others searching for the same solution.
Thanks !

Comment: The second option removes PowerButton Icon from the Ctrl+Alt+Del on Windows 7, thank you by this solution!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm searching for the same thing, but if you would like to hide the "Task-Manager"-Button, I knew which key you had to change:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System -> "DisableTaskMgr"=dword:00000001
```

This hides the Button from the "Control + Alt + Delete"-menu and also blocks the "Control + Shift + Escape"-Shortcut, not as the key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System -> "DisableTaskMgr"=dword:00000001
```

which only blocks opening the taskmanager and does not hide the button and block the keyboard.

And if you would like to remove the "Select-Network"-symbol, you might have to change the regkey:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System -> "DontDisplayNetworkSelectionUI"=dword:00000001
```

I hope this helps you and others with the same problem.